# Use variables in awk substr function

Tags: awk

All,
I have a string from which I want to extract a substring. The thing is that the starting position is stored in variable. AWK Doesn't seem to recognize the variable.

Here is the code

```
str="This is a test"  
s1="is"  
i=$(awk -v a="$str" -v b="$s1" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}')  
echo "$str" | awk '{print substr($0,$i)}'
```

But this doesn't work. How do coerce awk to recognize `i` ?

Answer (score 1):

With  **bash**:

```
awk -v value="$i" '{print substr($0,value)}' <<< "$str"
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is not being passed into `awk`. Instead of

```
echo "$str" | awk '{print substr($0,$i)}'
```

do

```
echo $str | awk -v i="$i" '{print substr($0,i)}'
```

However, the output is

```
% ./a.sh
is is a test
```

What is your intended output?

Comment: I want the output to be "is a test"

Answer (score 1):

Why not do all the processing in a single invocation of awk?

```
haystack="This is a test"
needle="is"
printf '%s\n' "$haystack" | awk -v "needle=$needle" '{
    i=index($0, needle)
    if (i) print substr($0, i)
}'
```

If you need your shell script to also see the value of `i`, you could add `> "/dev/tty"` to the end of the `print` command above, then add another line saying merely `print i` with no redirect, then wrap the whole `printf ... | awk ...` line in a `i=$(...)` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer to the original question: by escaping the quotation marks and letting the shell expand the variable:

```
awk '{print substr($0,'$i')}'
```

If it is suspected that the variable might contain blank space and other things and one wants it treated as a string in awk, one can just use even more quotation marks:

```
awk '{print index($0,"'"$s1"'")}'
```

...but one is often doing something less than optimal if it comes to this :-) .